# gnu parallel as a job queue

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have sets of jobs and all of the jobs can be run in parallel so I want to parallelize them for better throughput.

This is what I am currently doing:
I wrote a python script using multiprocessing library that runs jobs in a set at the same time. After all of the jobs in a set is finished, then another set of jobs (script) will be invoked. It is inefficient because each of job in a set has different execution time.

Recently, I noticed about GNU parallel and I think it may help to improve my script. However, a set of jobs have some pre-processing and post-processing tasks thus it is impossible to run random job.

In summary, I want to
1) make sure that pre-processing is completed before launching a job and
2) run post-processing after the jobs in a set are all completed.

And this is what I am trying to do:

1. Run separate script for each set of job.
2. Run pre-processing in script for each set and now it is free to run all jobs.
3. Each script registers jobs into job queue in GNU parallel.
4. GNU parallel runs job in a queue in parallel.
5. Each script monitors their own job is finished or not.
6. When all of the job in a set is done, run post-processing.

I am wondering how can I do such thing with GNU parallel or even not sure that GNU parallel is a write tool for this.

Comment: So, in rough terms you have S sets of jobs, and each set contains J jobs that each take around T seconds/minutes/hours. What are S, J and T roughly? All sets can be processed in parallel with each other - yes/no? Before each set is run the pre-process for that set must be run, followed by all the jobs in that set, followed by post-processing once the set is complete?

Comment: Roughly, S=~10, J=20~30, T=about an hour. Yes, All sets and jobs can be processed in parallel unless pre-processing of the job is completed. And yes, for each set, [pre-processing]->[run jobs/all jobs are finished]->[post-processing].

Comment: You mentioned a job-queue. Does the numbet of jobs change after the scripts have started or is it static and known in advance?

Comment: Are the pre- and post-processing scripts short or long relative to the jobs themselves?

Comment: The number of jobs is static and known in advance. pre-/post-processing are very short compared to jobs (few lines of code).

Comment: I am sure Ole (who develops GNU Parallel) will give you a definitive answer, but from what you have said, I think I'd invoke all S preprocessing jobs with one invocation of `parallel` and wait for them all to be done, then invoke another `parallel` with SxJ jobs in it. Separately, I'd let the post-processing jobs check every couple of minutes if all the files they need are available.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume you are limited by CPU (and not mem or I/O) then this might work:

```
do_jobset() {
  jobset=$1
  preprocess $jobset
  parallel --load 100% do_job ::: $jobset/*
  postprocess  $jobset
}
export -f do_jobset
parallel do_jobset ::: *.jobset
```

If `do_job` does not use a full CPU from the start, but takes 10 seconds to load data to be processed, add `--delay 10` before `--load 100%`.

The alternative is to do:

```
parallel preprocess ::: *.jobset
parallel do_job ::: jobsets*/*
parallel postprocess ::: *.jobset
```

Comment: Nice solution. Doubtless you saw I was alluding to your *alternative* solution in my comments. My only reservation is that if you wait for all jobsets to be processed before doing any postprocessing, you could potentially be waiting needlessly for the postprocessing of a job that otherwise was finished hours ago. Any bright ideas? That was what was behind my idea of the postprocessing to "poll" for sufficient data to start themselves ASAP.

Comment: The first solution will complete the postprocessing ASAP. In the second you are asking for a dependency graph, which GNU Parallel does not support. Then we are looking at Makefiles.

Comment: Ole: if you could find a way to use the $(SHELL) variable in GNU Make to use all the goodness in GNU Parallel the world would be a better place (for some of us, at least).

Comment: @Leo Are you aware of `make -j`?

Comment: @ole yup. It works nicely on one machine owned by one person. I'd love to combine `make --jobs` with GNU Parallel's load management, job control over the network, etc. features.

Comment: @Leo For load management look at `niceload` (part of GNU Parallel package).